# Finding Firefox resource hogs that freeze or slow it down

Tags: firefox, performance, freeze, performance-monitor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Determine which Firefox Add-ons are Using the Most Memory](https://superuser.com/questions/5939/how-to-determine-which-firefox-add-ons-are-using-the-most-memory)

I know I have many extensions (50+). Too many, perhaps ([case in point](http://beerpla.net/2009/04/11/essential-firefox-extensions-plugins-add-ons-and-tips-a-comprehensive-guide-part-1-tips/)). However, I am willing to pay for using so many with a slower Firefox.

However, some extensions **slow it down** TOO MUCH, to the point of **freezing**. While having a lot of extensions indeed slows me down, it's those 1 or 2 that completely kill it that I was to find.

Chrome already has a taskbar-like **monitor** for internal processes, and IE promises the same in the future. So how can we do the same in Firefox?

Specifically, how do you find which extension is **hogging** those resources and **freezing** the app? If it's a script (js, XUL?) that's killing it, how could I trace it? Maybe an extension that shows the currently running script/XUL process/subprocess/whatever - then when a freeze occurs, the name of the process would be frozen with it? What about tracing the **memory usage** from each extension?

I definitely do not feel like restarting Firefox disabling extensions one by one, especially since the freezes start to occur after Firefox has been running for some time.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/5939/ .  Browser speed and memory usage are *inversely* proportional, if there's any relationship at all.

Comment: this is not a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/5939/