# Is there a way to reduce the memory usage of Firefox?

Tags: firefox

On my notebook with 2GB and Windows XP, Firefox 3.5.2 uses about 150MB of the memory with 4 tabs open.  Is there a way to reduce the amount of memory that Firefox consumes?

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/5939/how-to-determine-which-firefox-add-ons-are-using-the-most-memory

Comment: I think you meant 150MB, not 150K, right?

Comment: Here in The Future, 4 tabs means 600mb - 1GB of RAM usage O.O

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This works wonders!](http://www.zolved.com/synapse/view_content/24939/How_to_reduce_the_memory_usage_on_Firefox)

- Check your Extensions and Themes. (By running Firefox in safe mode.)
- Check the Plug-ins.
- Clear Download History.
- Restart Firefox Periodically.
- Assign Memory Cache on Firefox. (`browser.cache.memory.enable` and `browser.cache.memory.capacity`)
- Release Memory when Firefox is minimized. (`config.trim_on_minimize`)

Answer (score 2):

I've been testing this for a few days and am very impressed. Reduced from average 150MB to 60MB

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11922

Of course, it's an extension so has its own footprint!

Comment: Thank you so much for this! After soooo long, Firefox is fast again =8-)

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions, default history setting is 90 days. This causes your Places database's size to skyrocket and can slow down Firefox considerably. **Reduce your history size** to something more suited to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Not to self-promote (I apologize), FireTune is a great little tool which can [speed up your Firefox](http://www.demogeek.com/2008/12/28/speed-up-firefox-to-the-extreme-with-firetune/) experience along with optimizing the memory usage of Firefox.

Comment: Self-promotion is alright (to a point) as long as your answers are relevant and helpful!

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest memory consumers in firefox is flash. If you can't disable the flash completely, try installing [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865). This will remove at least the flash ads (as long as the other ads)

And btw, 150MB is not that much at all.

Comment: You can try FlashBlock (don't have the URL handy) which blocks all flash until you tell it to run the flash video.

Comment: All adblockers seem to increase the memory as they load in a huge stylesheet to cancel out the adverts. I've found it's better to block the adverts at the hosts file level instead using https://www.abelhadigital.com/hostsman/ or pihole or something, and then you don't need an adblocker in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that has worked well for me is to be very selective with which extensions I have installed (or at least enabled).  If I find that I'm not using an extension very often, I'll disable it until I need it.