# How to determine bottlenecks in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, performance

I have some problems with Firefox 3.5 opening several tabs at once. It takes some seconds and that really annoys me.

I have some addons installed and now I want to determine which is the most braking one.

I could disable all addons and load them separately to see which slows Fx down but I don't want to do it manually.

So: How can I determine performance bottlenecks?

Comment: I found the thread with "Using memory" and read it. I don't think it's an exact duplicate because I'm searching for performance issues, not specific for memory issues. So I would like this question to be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do it manually.  First try running firefox in safe mode to make sure it is the add-ons slowing down your browser.  If the browser still takes the same amount of time to start, you might want to try clearing your private data.  Otherwise, you'll have to load the add-ons separately.

Comment: It's the answer: I did checked it, even if it's ugly. In my case, Firebug was activated for all websites and it still sucks performance. Not very nice, imho!

Comment: Glad to help! I've noticed that Firebug does slow down performance, and one of my friends told me that Adblock plus slows down the browser too, but I've never noticed that.

Comment: With ABP I don't have noticeable performance problems. Firebug decreases the speed very hard.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question asking about memory utilization of addons.
[**How to Determine which Firefox Add-ons are Using the Most Memory**](https://superuser.com/questions/5939/how-to-determine-which-firefox-add-ons-are-using-the-most-memory),
Maybe that will give you some clues.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a laptop that would do that. However it was a hardware issue - the keyboard would send keystroke to Firefox that I never generated. In the end I had to replace the keyboard.

Comment: Nice to know, very interesting.