# Does Firefox still have memory leaks?

Tags: firefox, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to reduce the memory usage of Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/24803/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-the-memory-usage-of-firefox)

I've had my Firefox 3.6.3 browser consume up to 1.5GB of RAM after a few days of usage without closing it. This is even true when, after a few days of opening/closing tabs, there's only 1 tab open. Does Firefox still have memory leaks?

Comment: Have you looked at their bug tracking page?

Comment: Related http://superuser.com/questions/122488/apparent-leak-in-mozilla-firefox http://superuser.com/questions/24803/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-the-memory-usage-of-firefox http://superuser.com/questions/5939/how-to-determine-which-firefox-add-ons-are-using-the-most-memory

Answer (score 1):

If you use addons, you could try switching them off and check if you still have the problem. In my experience half the problems are caused by the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some problems, but they seems to be getting better as the versions increase. I prefer [this solution](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Config.trim_on_minimize):

Browse to `about:config`, right-click and add a new Boolean named `config.trim_on_minimize`, set the value to `true`.

Alternatively, you could close the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Memory Fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/53880/) to release firefox memory periodically.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what OS you are using, and if you are looking at the resident memory size or the virtual memory size.  Under Linux, at least, the virtual memory size is a high water mark.  It is as much memory as the process has every used.  As long as the resident memory size is small, there shouldn't be much problem.  This should be true with OS X as well.  I'm not sure about Windows, but it wouldn't surprise me if it had the same behavior.