# Which Firefox plugin is eating all my memory?

Tags: firefox, plugins, memory-leaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Determine which Firefox Add-ons are Using the Most Memory](https://superuser.com/questions/5939/how-to-determine-which-firefox-add-ons-are-using-the-most-memory)

After 24 hours my Firefox uses nearly 2 GB RAM.
So I have to restart Firefox once a day.

How can I find out, which of my plugins has this memory leaks?

Any possibility to get a list of memory usage by plugin?

Comment: Which version of Firefox? I have encountered a memory leak with clean installations of Fx 9.0.1. Then again, 4GB of RAM was being filled up within 5 minutes.

Comment: Firefox hoards RAM on its own (Chrome does it, too). Often, it's not cookies but dynamic pages, i.e. if you keep GMail or Facebook open 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

A big culprit could be if you have a tab hoarding problem.  Keeping multiple tabs open for extended amounts of time will eat away at your memory for sure.

If that is the case, I suggest the following extension called UnloadTab:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unloadtab/?src=api

This extension stops your multiple tabs from running at the same time.  When you click on a tab that hasn't been touched in a while, it just reloads it.